# Process monitoring on Android/Linux slow

Tags: java, android, linux, performance

I want to monitor the processes of my Android phone. My approach so far was to execute commands with the Runtime. I then parse the output. The problem I am facing is that reading this data is not time-efficent. It takes about 900ms - 1300ms.

**Here is the code example:**

```
String cmd = "cat /proc/[0-9]*/status";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", cmd});
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

After this I loop over the reader with `.readLine();`

*How can I optimize this or what different approach might be worth a try.*

Thank you for your help.